# Create twin object a.k.a. inheritance clone

Tags: javascript, inheritance

The working `twin(source)` function below generates a new object with the same **own** properties as `source` and with the same parents (prototype chain). (e.g. `twin(isFinite)` would be `[object Object]` and `instanceof Function`) Does any native function provide the same effect?

```
/**
 * @param {Object|Function} source
 * @param {(Object|Function|null)=} parent defaults to source's parents
 * @return {Object}
 */
function twin(source, parent) {
    var twin, owned, i = arguments.length;
    source = i ? source : this; // use self if called w/o args
    parent = 2 == i ? parent : Object.getPrototypeOf(source);
    twin = Object.create(parent);
    owned = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source);
    for (i = owned.length; i--;) {
        twin[owned[i]] = source[owned[i]];
    }
    return twin;
}
```

**Update:** A `.twin` method is available in [blood](https://github.com/ryanve/blood).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
obj= eval(uneval(objSource));
```

It only works in FF but the idea is to serialize an object and the eval the serialized string instantiating (prototyping) a new object with the same properties as the first one.

You can use also the function JSON.stringify as the "uneval" function.